# Cpu not boosting when undervolting

Tags: cpu, cpu-temperature, undervolting

First of all here is my spec & configuration:
Ryzen 5 3500 3.6Ghz(stock)
Inno3d gtx1070 8Gb(stock)
Team TForce Vulcan z 2x8gb 3000Mhz(OC to 3200Mhz)
Asrock B450M steel legend
Except for memory, voltage, and boot option I didn't change anything else on bios.
Ambience temperature at 21-25C

I recently build this desktop, previously my cpu run too hot with stock cooler at 45-60C on idle(bad installation I guess) so I changed the cooler to coolermaster hyper ii turbo, it lower the cpu temperature to 35-50C on idle but only for 1 week and then it float above 40C. I tried undervolting after I do some research that it help reduce temperature, and it did help keep my temperature under 40C. Before I undervolt my cpu can boost to 3.95Ghz but after undervolting it won't boost and maxed at advertised speed at 3.6Ghz.

My question:

- is it possible to boost when undervolted?
- do I need to change something else so I can boost when undervolted?(no from what I read if pbo is already enabled, edit: it's set to auto, i tried enabling it with same result)
- is my cpu temperature acceptable/normal?
- if not what else can I do to optimize it?

Comment: Instead of undervolting, make sure you have updated your BIOS for best compatibility with ryzen 3xxx CPU's, have windows 10 May 2019 (or higher) with AMD power plan selected. Also read the following article https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/cbls9g/the_final_word_on_idle_voltages_for_3rd_gen_ryzen/ to get an idea on why the results you're seeing may be wrong.

Comment: My board ship with BIOS version 2.90 which according to asrock site is the latest version, windows is also the latest build. I tried setting the voltage to auto and use ryzen master, and hwinfo one at a time like the article said to monitor the temperature with more or less same result above 40C even with amd balanced power plan, so I think the reading is correct. Also I tried running cinebench 20 and it boost fine to 4Ghz when voltage is set to auto, so I guess undervolting do prevent boost because the voltage is limited right?

Comment: Also already updated the chipset before this, so afaik already updated everything that may have affect this. I read for amd cpu the temperature should be around 10-20C higher than ambience using stock.